# Python Django performing independent interval tasks

Tags: django, intervals, django-celery, periodic-task, django-celery-beat

It became necessary, in certain situations, to create a periodic task that will check the state of the user every minute. For this I am using django_celery_beat + PeriodicTask + IntervalSchedule

When this task is 1, everything is fine. But when a new one is created for another user, the task execution shifts: for example, the first user was checked every minute starting from 10:14:40, the next check should have been at 10:15:40, but a new task was created at 10:15:35 and both users end up being verified at 10:16:35

How can I solve my problem? each user should be checked every minute within its own interval.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. But, you can have one periodic task running which will loop through all of the specified users and check their values. That way the single task can be on the beat for a specified interval.

Comment: The start date of the check is very important. If I started checking the user at 10:40:35, the next check should be at 10:41:35. The second user is checked for example at 10:40:49 seconds and so on.

If I use a common interval for everyone, then the checks will be at the same time, and this is not suitable.